# Does a non-clustered index performance increase when there is also a clustered (PK) index?

Tags: t-sql, indexing

I have a very large table with two indexes on it, but no PK (clustered) index.

Would the performance of the two indexes increase if there was also a clustered index on the table, even if I have to "contrive" one from an identity column?

Comment: Looking through the database [ I've inherited it :( ] and most tables have lots of sensible indexes but no PK/Clustered index.

Comment: It may, it may not. You should take a copy, try applying the clustered index, and run a realistic workload from your system against it. Also - a) You shouldn't need to comment directly on your own questions/answers - if you have more to add, use the edit link, and b) You should avoid conflating Primary Keys and Clustered Indexes. The two concepts are distinct.

Comment: A select statement on a heap (table without a clustered index) which requires an _RID lookup_ will instead use a _bookmark lookup_ when there is a clustered index. There is some argument that a bookmark lookup is less efficient than an RID lookup. All of this is under particular scenarios and workloads. You really need to do some analysis in a test system. Observe and compare query plans and performance.

Comment: Please add more information about the system that uses the databases. Is it a read-heavy system or a write-heavy one? If it is a system with many inserts you don't want to make a clustered index on a column which has no internal order (such as a GUID) since the database is physically arranged according to the clustered key.

Answer (score 1):

a well chosen clustered index can do miracles to your performance. Why? The clustered index defines how your data is physically stored on your Hard Disk. Choosing a good Clustered index will ensure you get Sequential IO instead of Random IO. Therefore this is a great performance gain, because the bottleneck in most database setups are the Hard Drives and the IO action.

Try to create your clustered index on a value that is used a lot by joins.

If you just put it on your Primary key your performance will still improve as the NON_Clustered will use the Clustered for their seek operation, which will avoid table scans.

Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

It's more like the opposite, non-clustered indexes suffer from clustered indexes:

http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2014-01/unreasonable-defaults-primary-key-clustering-key

However, if you manage to replace one of your non-clustered indexes by a clustered indexes, overall performance might increase...or decrease. Really depends on your workload.